# Is CPYTOIMPF to qtemp faster than to other library?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am a programmer working on IBM AS400 V5R4. I create 2 CL programs, both of which use CPYTOIMPF to format a list of AS400 PFs to character delimited files. The difference between them is: one formats files to qtemp(PGM A), while the other one formats files to a library other than qtemp(PGM B).

I called the 2 program separately to format about 90 files, with total about 8 million records. Both of the programs consumed more than 1300s CPU time, while PGM A used about 5% less CPU time than PGM B. I have tryied several times and the result is similar.

May I know why CPYTOIMPF to qtemp is faster than copy to other library, though just a little difference?

Comment: First thing I would expect to be different is authority checking. I wouldn't be surprised if QTEMP authorizes relatively quickly, but I don't know of any docs that mention it.

Comment: Most likely the difference was per a failure to conduct valid testing; valid performance comparisons are not easily achieved. Minimally, the order of the two test variants should be reversed over each of multiple iterations, and the multiple runs of each variation should be averaged having discarded the first run of each; only then make a comparison, but comparing the _averages_ betwixt. Next to minimally, the storage pools should be cleared before each run, or cleared before each run of a separate test of multiple iterations so a comparison can be made of each of the four averaged results.

Comment: @user2338816 Authority checking should be no different for QTEMP than any other permanent library. Despite the name, QTEMP is a permanent object, as are the external objects created within a QTEMP; they could be _moved_ to another library, so temporary would be a conundurm. An object could be restored or created into QTEMP by a switched-to user or assigned private authority as part of the user profile attributes and accessed with program adopted authority -- all the same issues for any other library, so there are [almost surely] no shortcuts in any OS code for the QTEMP library in that regard.

Comment: @CRPence Hard to be certain from outside IBM, so I can't disagree. There are a couple oddities, though, e.g., DSPOBJAUT for QTEMP returns CPD2258; so it always feels as if there's a difference.

Comment: Yeah, that preventive for authority display [¿to conceal any auth change that was not also prevented?] I infer to be an implication that QTEMP aut is not typically checked by the security component (SY), but the authority to the library is just a small part of the overhead, which is mostly the objects. The OP surely would be data, not object\aut related; i.e. hyperbole for emphasis. A duplicate [not proxy] of an Aut Chg *CMD object, altered [STRSST\D/A/D], might be able to effect GRT\RVK to enable a test; i.e. enforcement of "QTEMP not allowed" is in the command, possibly not also in the CPP.

Answer (score 2):

QTEMP and it's contents are not required to survive beyond the life of the job, so it may well be optimized to not commit things to disk or to do so less often, and it may not need to create file system transactions for object changes either, since if the system goes down uncontrolled QTEMP is simply blown away with the job.

Also, QTEMP does not need to worry about security resolution and object controls since it is private to the job.

These things, and similar, can make accessing QTEMP require less work than a normal persistent library.

Comment: There is almost nothing about QTEMP sufficiently different, for which the alluded performance difference should be visible. Performance testing must be done very _scientifically_ and laypersons are unlikely able to achieve valid comparisons. The above allusion to reduced "security" and "controls" in effect for QTEMP [and no way I can think of to state this without sounding crass] is bunk; the object-level authority\security is and must be maintained even in QTEMP -- only true-temporary objects are exempt [per no owner], and both the QTEMP library and the objects within are permanent objects.

Comment: @CRPence, I was only offering possibilities to explain why the OP might see the difference in performance he's seeing. There are any number of ways the system could optimize QTEMP due to it's special nature. But nice to know there are experts here to throw their (imagined) weight around. I speak of what I know from many years experience on the S34, S38, and AS400/iSeries/System-i/IBM-i. However, keep on being an arse. Oh, and here's a nice way to say it, "The above allusion ... is likely incorrect". You are probably wrong, but, if you have some real knowledge beyond conjecture, do share.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be an arse; just trying to discourage anyone accepting allusions to the miniscule differences between QTEMP and other *permanent* libraries as having any significant effect on the performance of mostly database write activity, as legitimate. FWiW, my comments reflect many years coding the OS [mostly database] in the IBM Rochester labs. FWiW: For some short period of time, the librarian component of the OS made a blunder in making the QTEMP libraries *temporary*, but the database component ensured they made a quick reversion of that implementation due to the nasty effects.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get an answer here. Try posting it to [MIDRANGE-L](http://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/midrange-l). There is a large community of IBM i (or AS/400) experts there. Someone could probably answer it there.

Answer (score 1):

QTEMP is always in the library list of a iSeries Job (with a normal configured iSeries). Did you do your - interesting! - experiment with a library that is in the library list too?

I don't know if syslibl, curlibl of usrlibl may be of any importance.

Comment: QTEMP is only in the library list if it's explicitly included in the list, just like any other library. If it isn't, objects must be qualified. Easy to test simply by using EDTLIBLE and removing it. Then create an object in QTEMP and try to access it without qualification. You should notice that it'll generally be added to every *JOBD and to system value QUSRLIBL. (That might be considered to mean a "normal configured iSeries", but it's still necessary actually to ensure that it's done.)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting experiment.

Are you using the SIZE atttribute on the CRTPF command when you create the output file in QTEMP or the other library?  I'd suspect extending the file is faster in QTEMP than it is in the other library.  Setting the number of records in the SIZE attribute to the number of records on the input file might remove the difference in performance as the files no longer have to be extended.

Comment: The extend algorithm is the same irrespective the library; implemented in the LIC DB, that feature does not interrogate the library of the DataSpace [and can not because the object is not in a library] nor seek that information from the member to which that dataspace belongs -- the work involving the data is done library-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

In `QTEMP`, generally, you just create the file with `CRTFILE(*YES)`

The difference could be simply the time to delete the file before recreating it, or with more impact the time to clear the file: `MBROPT(*REPLACE)`

Comment: The CPYTOIMPF has no CRTFILE parameter. Re time to delete or clear: any differences would most likely indicate an error in the test-case, rather than any legitimate difference in the amount of work for which there would be an expectation of a legitimate difference in the amount of wall-clock time to complete that work.

Comment: Oups, yes, you're right. I focused on a copy problem between QTEMP and a real Library, but for CPYTOIMPF it should not change anything: the destination file must exist before copying...